# Type '<typename>' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, xaml, uwp

I have UWP (VB.NET) app which buttons are created dynamically. By the time buttons are created, I also created click events for them dynamically. Click event is to navigate to different pages using `frame.navigate(GetType(<typename>))`. However, I got an error of: **Type 'T' is not defined.**

'T' is type I declared in my code. Please see my code below. Your help is very much appreciated.

```vb
Public ButtonPipingSample As Button 'used for sizing and margins
Public ButtonsPiping As New ArrayList

Private Sub PipingToolsButtonsLoad()
    Dim XmlToolsDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Tools.xml")

    Dim query = From t In XmlToolsDoc.Descendants("TOOL")
                Where t.Element("CATEGORY").Value.ToUpper = "PIPING"
                Select t

    Dim PipingButtons(query.Count - 1, 10) As String
    Dim NumberOfPipingButtons = query.Count - 1

    For i = 0 To NumberOfPipingButtons
        'ID, NAME, CATEGORY, margin, horizontalcontentalignment, background, borderbrush, width, height, fontsize
        PipingButtons(i, 0) = query.ElementAt(i).Element("ID").Value   'ID
        PipingButtons(i, 1) = query.ElementAt(i).Element("NAME").Value 'NAME
        PipingButtons(i, 2) = query.ElementAt(i).Element("CATEGORY").Value   'CATEGORY
        PipingButtons(i, 3) = "0,0,30,0"   'Margin
        PipingButtons(i, 4) = "Center" 'HorizontalContentAlignment
        PipingButtons(i, 5) = "#33109772"   'Background
        PipingButtons(i, 6) = "Green"   'BorderBrush
        PipingButtons(i, 7) = "170"    'Width
        PipingButtons(i, 8) = "80"   'Height
        PipingButtons(i, 9) = "13"   'FontSize
        PipingButtons(i, 10) = query.ElementAt(i).Element("HINT").Value
    Next

    'Clear Buttons Array
    ButtonsPiping.Clear()

    'Create buttons
    For i = 0 To NumberOfPipingButtons
        Dim ButtonPiping As New Button
        Dim TextBlockButtonPiping As New TextBlock

        TextBlockButtonPiping.Text = PipingButtons(i, 1)
        TextBlockButtonPiping.HorizontalAlignment = True
        TextBlockButtonPiping.TextWrapping = True
        TextBlockButtonPiping.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
        ButtonPiping.Content = TextBlockButtonPiping
        ButtonPiping.Margin = New Thickness(15, 0, 30, 15)

        ButtonPiping.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.DeepPink)
        ButtonPiping.BorderBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)
        ButtonPiping.Width = PipingButtons(i, 7)
        ButtonPiping.Height = PipingButtons(i, 8)
        ButtonPiping.FontSize = PipingButtons(i, 9)
        ButtonPiping.Name = PipingButtons(i, 0)

        AddHandler ButtonPiping.Click, AddressOf ButtonPipingToolClick

        ButtonPipingSample = ButtonPiping
        ButtonsPiping.Add(ButtonPiping)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonPipingToolClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim T As Type = Type.GetType(sender.name)


    Frame.Navigate(GetType(T))
End Sub
```

Comment: Does `Type` have a `Type`?

Comment: @AJD : A `Type` is a `Type` is a `Type` is a `Type` is a ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the logic in your code, I think `ButtonPipingToolClick` should contain

```vb
Dim T As Type = Type.GetType(sender.name)
Dim X As Type = T ' You aleady know that T is of Type Type
Frame.Navigate(X) ' or T
```

Comment: I tryied different methods like remove the 'X' and instead use [frame.navigate(T)], then used [frame.navigate(type.gettype(sender.name))], still no success.

Comment: @neutralizer : Either of those two should work. Are you sure that the type names are complete? Does the framework actually manage to resolve them?

Comment: @neutralizer: added another point I have spotted. Might have some relevance.

Comment: @AJD : In response to your edit: `t` is declared by the `From` statement, it's like when you make a `For`-loop: `For Each item In myList` - the statement declares the variable for you. As for `query` he does declare it: `Dim query = ...`

Comment: If the Page is "MyPage" and the Namespace the page is Residing in Is "MyApplication.Pages", Then the `Type.GetType` will be `Type.GetType("MyApplication.Pages.MyPage")`. `Type.GetType("MyPages")` will throw an error.

Comment: in the code i reference the type 'T' to page name. The name of the Type comes from [sender.name] which is button name as well as it is the name of the page I want to open. Using [frame.navigate(gettype(T)) does not work. However instead of 'T' type when I use exactly the name of page it works.

Comment: MyApplication.Pages.Mypage does not work. There must be a way to refer to variably defined pages.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like that.

```
Private Sub ButtonPipingToolClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)


    Dim ans As String = "Mechanical Engineering Tools, Version=1.0.0.0"

    Dim an As New System.Reflection.AssemblyName(ans)

    Dim a As Assembly = Assembly.Load(an)

    'TxtBlockTypeTest.Text = a.GetTypes().ToString

    For Each T As Type In a.GetTypes()

        Dim ButtonName As String = "_" & sender.name.ToString

        If ButtonName = T.Name.ToString Then
            Frame.Navigate(T)
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```